# Compare a file size between 2 servers (Unix & Windows)

Tags: unix, batch-file, ssh

I need to write a Windows batch file to resolve the below issue.

I need to make sure that a file is completely transferred from it's origin server (Unix) to the target server (Windows).

I am trying to compare the file size between the two servers, the solution needs to be in a Windows batch file (I am having trouble with connecting to a remote Unix server using SSH in a DOS batch file)

Comment: How do you transfer the file? ftp?

Comment: i am not sure about that as i only have access to the Unix and Windows server; the transfert si being done by a third party tool on a different server (CFT...)

Comment: If the files are text, then the transfer tool probably converts line endings from UNIX to DOS/Windows. The file sizes will be different. What SSH are you using on Windows?

Comment: files format and types will change every time.i tested file size after it was completely trasnfered and it had the same size in octet on both Unix & Windows server. i am thinking about using the DOS command SSH. Is that possible ?

Comment: Ok, so it appears the files are transferred in binary mode (FTP terms). Have you found an `ssh` command on DOS/Windows? You may need Cygwin or PuTTY plink.

Answer (score 0):

From the fact you can use SSH, I assume you also have an SFTP access.

You can use following PowerShell script using [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell).

```powershell
param (
    $sessionUrl = "sftp://user:mypassword;fingerprint=ssh-rsa-xxxxxxxxx...=@example.com/",
    $localPath = "C:\path\file.dat",
    $remotePath = "/path/file.dat"
)

$localSize = (Get-Item $localPath).Length
Write-Host "$localPath has $localSize bytes"

# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot "WinSCPnet.dll")

# Setup session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
$sessionOptions.ParseUrl($sessionUrl)

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

# Connect
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

$remoteSize = $session.GetFileInfo($remotePath).Length
$session.Dispose()

Write-Host "$remotePath has $remoteSize bytes"

# Compare cheksums
if ($localSize -eq $remoteSize)
{
    Write-Host "Match"
    $result = 0
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Does NOT match"
    $result = 1
}

exit $result
```

---

Or even better, compare file checksums, not just size, if your server support that, see:
[Verify checksum of a remote file against a local file over SFTP/FTP protocol](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_verify_file_checksum)

---

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*